# Calculate the Entropy Change if 5 Previously Tossed Dice Are Turned to All "1"

Tags: probability, dice, entropy

Relevant Equations: S = Boltzmann*ln(W) where S is entropy and W is the number of microstates.

I have thought about this two ways.

1 way. Look at each die separately. Let macrostate 1 = number of dots is 1, macrostate 2 is number of dots is not 1.

Then the die has 1 microstate for macrostate 1, and 5 microstates for macrostate 2.

Thus the entropy is S = Boltzmann * ln(5) if the die does not read 1.

Now we repeat this for all 5 die and so our entropies add to get S = n*Boltzmann*ln(5) where n is the number of die that do not show 1.

Since we are looking for the change in S, and the number of microstates for rolling a 1 is just 1, our entropy for that is 0.

Thus, our change in entropy is (-n)*boltzmann*ln(5). Our entropy decreases.

Way number 2 - examine all die at once.

macrostate 1 = all 1. macrostate 2 = not all 1.

Then there are 6^5 = 7776 total microstates, and only 1 of those is all 1. Then there are 7775 microstates that do not give one, and so S = boltzmann * ln(7775). Like above, we subtract that since our final state of all 1 has entropy 0.

Thus, our change is -Boltzmann*ln(7775).

Obviously I am doing something wrong, because I got a number for way 2 but a formula for way 1. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What you've calculated in Method 1 is the change in entropy from *all* five dice showing *not* `1` to *all* five dice showing `1`.   You haven't included the possibility that one *or more* die starts out showing `1`.   Hence you've counted only $5^5$ microstates.

What you've calculated in Method 2 is the change in entropy from *some of the* five dice show *not* `1` to *all* five dice show `1`.   This includes the possibility that one or more die starts out showing `1` with *the exception* of the possibility that all five dice show `1`.   Hence you've counted $6^5-1$ microstates.

---

However, you really should *not* exclude the possibility that *all* five die show `1` after being **tossed randomly**.   They *could* start out in the desired microstate as there's no bias against it.

(Note that the initial and final macrostates in problems such as this one are *not necessarily* composed of mutually exclusive microstates.)

Try:

- **Initial Macrostate:** "the dice are randomly tossed": $6$ microstates for each die; or $6^5$ microstates for the five dice.
- **Final Macrostate:** "the dice are all set to show `1`".  $1$ microstate for each die; or $1$ microstate for the five dice.

Using with this your method 1 and method 2 should give the same result: $-5 k_{\small B}\ln 6$